# Silverlight scrollviewer's scrollbar invisible when not active

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How do i detect when scrolling is unavailable to the scrollviewer control and make it invisible. And the scrollbar only visible when there is a chance to scoll up or down.

Thanks,
Shawn McLean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`  acheives this goal with out you needing to do any "detecting" of your own.